# Lightroom is not showing Photo correctly

Tags: lightroom, troubleshooting, lightroom-4

I have 3-4 Photos in LR that in Library / Develop / Preview looks like this:

[image]

The File itself seems to be fine as it show properly in other tools.

Any idea how to fix this in LR?

Comment: What other tools does it show properly in, and are they displaying the jpg preview embedded in the RAW file, or are they actually displaying the same RAW? Have you tried removing it from LR and reimporting it?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried with irfanview first, then with another tool showing the same problem. So I guess that irfanview is showing the jpg and the raw is dammaged.

Comment: Could you try updating your video drivers? It may have been a while since you updated it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't a LR Bug / Problem. In fact the RAW was dammaged.

Some Tools like Irfanview use the embedded JPG do show the picture another tool showed the same result as LR.

Comment: I had something like this happen when I had faulty RAM. Luckily the raw file was still good as nothing ever writes it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with not redrawing/refreshing the content of the display in general.

Could be a video card driver issue. Try updating the video driver of your computer by going to the manufacturer's site and get the latest driver directly from them.

ALso, Adobe just released LR 4.3, you may want to look into updating?

I've recently read about some video issues for Mac users with both LR and PS where weird behavior like this appears after doing things like moving or creating new windows and when using some plugins. Adobe knows about these video issues to some degree, but not sure what, if anything, became of the problem.