# Can Lightroom detect corrupted images?

Tags: lightroom, data-corruption

Can Lightroom detect all sorts of corrupted images? I.e. make a smart collection where these are collected. I know that some corrupted images often are displayed as missing, and can be found automatically through this, but does this apply to all sorts of corrupted images?

Comment: DNGs provide a checksum to verify, but there are other ways. Lightroom could store a checksum per image in its catalog or in the sidecar file. In order to discover the corruption the image would have to be parsed by Lightroom - scanning all your images for corruption sounds like it would be slow.

Comment: I don't know about collecting them in a smart collection, but at least with the latest version of Lightroom, it does seem to put a small trianglular ! icon on each photo in grid-mode library view when an image cannot be loaded. This can be due to the image existing on disk but not being readable, being missing, etc.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. Lately I had a corruped one (see my post on [Lightroom is not showing Photo correctly](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30535/lightroom-is-not-showing-photo-correctly))
and LR didn't mention anything.